Discord.py app_commands syncing issue
import discord

from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=intents)


OWNER_ID = 683313053605167185


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('ready')
    try:
        guild = discord.Object(id= 1296389488972398644) 
        synced = await client.tree.sync(guild=guild)
        print(f"synced {len(synced)} command(s) to {guild.id}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error syncing commands: {e}")

@client.tree.command(description="gets the bots ping!")
async def ping(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Tupiful Utilities Bot ping")
    embed.add_field(name="Bot ping", value=f"{round(client.latency * 1000)}ms")
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral = True)

client.run(# My Token)

My bot syncs the ping command to a test server however doesn’t sync the ping command to my main server?
I have tried logging errors (none show), messing around with the server itself and even made a whole new bot however the same problem comes up

When you synced your commands, you set the guild parameter, which by the documentation, means you're specifically syncing to that guild and that guild only. To sync it globally, as in to sync it across all servers, leave guild as None.
await client.tree.sync()

If you want to specifically sync commands to certain guilds, you also need the guild or guilds parameter in your command. Refer to here.
guild = discord.Object(id= 1296389488972398644)
@client.tree.command(description="gets the bots ping!", guild=guild)
async def ping(interaction: discord.Interaction):

Additionally, if you have other global commands that you want to sync to this guild, you have to add copy_global_to above where you sync to the guild.
client.tree.copy_global_to(guild=guild)
synced = await client.tree.sync(guild=guild)


the biggest issue is that the ID used in the guild parameter is the id of the guild i want to sync to...

Thanks for clarifying, I've edited my response
